# How do academics in the Social Sciences use "mental maps" and why should college-bound students study them?

Tags: research-process, tools, social-science

I teach secondary school Social Studies. As you may know, public school teachers must teach to state standards. My state's standards for Social Studies includes many references to the importance and use of "mental maps".

E.g. here are some quotes from the standards: "construct and use mental maps of locales, regions, and the world that demonstrate understanding of relative location, direction, size, and shape;"

"describe ways that mental maps reflect attitudes about places;"

I took many undergraduate and graduate courses in history, geography, cultural studies, linguistics, musicology, and various social science disciplines, but never remember mental maps ever being a topic, nor being used as a tool by academics.

Is it just a fun exercise or of some general value to the greater contribution of knowledge in the world? What sort of academics will use this and how is that an important concept for my secondary students, who are in a college prep track, to understand?

Comment: What? I don't understand. Are they supposed to imagine their home town and map that onto their understanding of sentence structure somehow?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_mapping) looks like a good starting point.

Comment: @DanRomik I did encounter this article, and it seems giving random examples, none which seem to support the notion this is a tool of significant importance that students need to learn.

Comment: Ok, just trying to be helpful. It sounds like it’s not so much a tool as simply a convenient figure of speech for the way geographical information gets represented and perceived by human brains and how such representations affect people’s attitudes and social interactions. At least from the examples you cited it doesn’t sound like there’s much more to it than that. My guess is it probably matters very little to your students whether your discuss mental maps extensively or not. But that’s just my lay person’s opinion.

Comment: I sometimes use them to make sure the students understand how the various course concepts connect. Useful near the end of the semester when we have covered a lot of ground and you want to make sure people are bringing it all together. More a teaching tool.

Comment: On the research side, being able to make a diagram to make sense of qualitative relationships is quite helpful. Or to show how various aspects of a system fit together/ work. Or see “directed analytic graphs” for causal inference.

Comment: Voting to close -- see my comment on the answer below for a rationale.